# Importing typescript from external node modules

Tags: node.js, typescript

I want to split my application into different node modules and have a main module which builds all other modules as well and I want to use typescript with es6 modules.

Here is my planned project structure:

- main

  - node_modules

    - dep-a
    - dep-b
- framework

  - interfaces

    - IComponent.ts
- dep-a

  - components

    - test.ts
  - node_modules

    - framework
  - index.ts
- dep-b

  - node_modules

    - framework

I want to be able to define interfaces in framework which can be consumed in dep-a, dep-b and main.

How do I set up this correctly? Can I compile everything from my main-module? Do I need to create different bundles for framework, dep-a, ... and another typing file? What is the best approach for this?

I already set up some test files and folders and used npm link to link the dependencies and webpack to bundle the files and I am always running into issues with files not being found:

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module 'framework/interfaces/IComponent'
```

and

```
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./components/test
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*TL;DR* generate declarations for the modules using `declaration: true` in `tsconfig.json` and specify the file for your generated typings  in the `typings` entry of the `package.json` file

### framework

Use a `tsconfig` file similar to this:

```
{
       "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "declaration": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        ...
    },
    "files": [
         ...
    ]
}
```

The important bit is `declaration: true` which will generate internal declarations in the dist directory

Assuming there is an `index.ts` file which (re)exports all the interesting parts of `framework`, create a `package.json` file with a `main` and `typings` entry pointing to, respectively, the generated js and the generated declaration, i.e.

```
{
   "name": "framework",
   "main": "dist/index.js",
   "typings": "dist/index.d.ts",
   ...
 }
```

Commit this module to a git repo, say bitbucket at : "https://myUser@bitbucket.org/myUser/framework.git"

### dep-a

in `package.json` create a dependency to `framework`

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "framework":     "https://myUser@bitbucket.org/myUser/framework.git"
    },
}
```

That is it.

```
import * from 'framework'
```

will pull the dependency *with* the typings, automatically

Obviously, it is possible to do with *dep-a* what was done with *framework* i.e. generate the declarations, update package.json and use *dep-a* as a module with embedded typings in *main*

note: a file URL will do in package.json/dependencies if you do not want go to via an external git repo

Comment: thx for the quick response. This is more or less working. Only problem I am now facing with webpack is, that sourcemaps for dep-a are not working ... Do you know of any possibility to compile dep-a in main as well to get proper sourcemaps?

Comment: compile dep-a in main: I do not believe this is possible unless you move the dep-a sources to main (and it is not a dependency anymore). soucemaps: we do not ship sourcemaps with our own modules , so I have not tested. What i know is fine with webpack is accessing the js from the `~` source in the dubugger. Having the map files along with the js in `dist/` for dep-a does not work ?

Comment: hm, ok, thx. The sourcemaps in deps are there but seem not to be loaded from webpack. I created an issue in the webpack repo: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1695

Answer (score 2):

What arrived in TypeScript 1.6 is `typings` property in `package.json` module. You can [check the relevant issue on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/247).

So assuming you want to create separate modules ( dep-a, framework ). You can do the following :

```
main.ts                 // (1)
package.json            // (2)
node_modules/
  dep_a/                
    index.js            // (3)
    index.d.ts          // (4)
    package.json        // (5)
    node_modules/
      framework/ 
        index.js        // (6)
        index.d.ts      // (7)
        package.json    // (8)
```

So let's see what you have in your files :

```
//(1) main.ts
import * as depA from "depA";

console.log(depA({ a : true, b : 2 }) === true) // true;
```

---

```
//(2) package.json
{
  name: "main",
  dependencies: {
    "dep_a" : "0.0.1"
  }
  ...
}
```

---

For `depA`

```
//(3) dep_a/index.js
module.exports = function a(options) { return true; };
```

---

```
//(4) dep_a/index.d.ts;

import * as framework from "framework";

export interface IDepA extends framework.IFramework {
   a : boolean
}

export default function a(options: IDepA) : boolean;
```

---

```
//(5) dep_a/package.json
{
  name: "dep_a",
  dependencies: {
    "framework" : "0.0.1"
  },
  ...
  typings : "index.d.ts" // < Magic happens here
}
```

---

For `framework`

```
//(6) dep_a/node_modules/framework/index.js
module.exports = true // we need index.js here, but we will only use definition file
```

---

```
//(7) dep_a/node_modules/framework/index.d.ts;

export interface IFramework {
   b : number;
}
```

---

```
//(8) dep_a/node_modules/framework/package.json
{
  name: "framework"
  ...
  typings : "index.d.ts"
}
```

What I don't include in this answer ( for clarity ) is another compilation phase, so you could actually write the modules ( `dep_a`, `framework` ) with typescript and then compile them to `index.js` before you use them.

Answer (score 1):

For a detailed explanation and some background also see: https://medium.com/@mweststrate/how-to-create-strongly-typed-npm-modules-1e1bda23a7f4