# Correctly writing and importing custom node modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, node-modules

#### EDIT

This is **NOT** a TypeScript question but rather a best-practices one. The example in TypeScript but really, the question here is how do I, correctly, expose multiple exports from multiple files that compose a module, and how to correctly import them.

---

#### EDIT 2

There's still something not right

So, on my Module2's index I have this:

```
export * from "./queryFilter";
```

On Module1 user.ts I import it by using

```
import { queryFilter as QueryFilter } from "Module2";
(...)
var User = {...}
User.getById = (userId: string) => {
...
}
export { User }
```

And my Module1's index.ts I export it as
    `export * from "./model/user";`

Then, on my main project I import it using

```
import * as Schema from "Module1";
var User = Schema.User;
```

However, this throws an error whenever I try to call User.getById:
`Debug: internal, implementation, error
    TypeError: Uncaught error: Cannot read property 'getByEmail' of undefined`

From this approach, what am I doing wrong???

---

I'm writing a couple of node modules for the first time ever and I do have some questions regarding proper declaration/usage of this.

So I'm creating a module that will require another custom module, let's call them Module1 and Module2.

So, Module1 is required by the main application, but Module1 also requires Module2.

Now on Module2 I have a bunch of files and on each one I export what I need. Here's a sample:

Module2 - Utils.ts:

```
"use strict"
const RandomString = require("randomstring");

let randomString = (numCharacters: number) => {
    return RandomString.generate({
        length: numCharacters,
        capitalization: 'uppercase',
        charset: 'alphanumeric'
    });
}

module.exports.randomString = randomString;
```

Module2 - queryFilter.ts:

```
"use strict"

export default class QueryFilter {
    name: string;
    op: string;
    value: any;
    scope: string;

    constructor(name: string, op: string, value: any, scope: string) {
        this.name = name;
        this.op = op;
        this.value = value;
        this.scope = scope;
    }

    public static GetConditionQuery(filters: QueryFilter[], params: string[]) {
        (...)
    }

    public static queryComparator(value1: any, value2: any, operator: string): any {
        (...)
    }
}
```

On Module1, I added Module2 to `package.json` so when I want to use `QueryFilter`, for instance, I require it like this:

Module1 - Class.ts:

```
import { QueryFilter } = require("Module2").queryFilter;
```

Now my question is, is it enough to export individual items from each file in my Module2 and use it in this fashion? Or should I have a `index` that would export every file from Module2 so that Module1 can see them?

Something along the lines of:

Module2 - index.ts:

```
export "./utils"
export "./queryFilter"
(...)
```

What is the correct way of doing this? I'm a total newb to this and the docs I've read didn't shed any light on this..

Best Regards

Comment: @Darkrum thank you for your helpful answer, because this is really one of the worst examples of the differences between TS and JS

Comment: Someone will have to come up with a definitive guide on this... I have no time right now but can you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34041242/1263942) to start with (framework is your module2) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34272128/typescript-declaration-and-commonjs/34272618#34272618)

Comment: Tks @BrunoGrieder. This is not a TypeScript question per se. It is written in TypeScript but the question here is how to expose a bunch of declared exports from multiple files into a single import/require call.

Comment: Note that aside from your `import = require`, your `export` syntax is actually exactly what is used in ES6.  Alter `import { QueryFilter } = require('Module2').queryFilter` to `import { queryFilter as QueryFilter } from 'Module2'` and you have ES6 syntax right there.

Comment: @Zed_Blade check my answer below (js ES6 would be the same): create an index.ts/index.js that re-exports what you want to make public of your library

Comment: @BrunoGrieder I did. I'm already refactoring. I like to test things before marking answers as accepted ;)

Comment: @Zed_Blade  :) +1

Answer (score 1):

Following your last comment, this the 'typescript solution' for creating a module/library. The solution would be similar for "pure" ES6; typings in Typescript just add a small layer of difficulty.

Assuming you write a module/library with multiple files:

*func1.ts*

```
export func1(param1: number): string { ... }
```

*func2.ts*

```
export func2(): number { ....}
```

Create an *index.ts* which re-exports the interesting parts of your module/lib

```
export * from './func1'
export * from './func2'
....
```

Obviously you can choose to (re)export and make public only part of the code e.g. `export { thisFunc, thatClass } from './anotheFile'`

Compile the module with `declarations` and `commonjs` flags, and make sure that the `package.json` `main` points to `index.js`, while the `typings` entry points to the generated `index.d.ts`

This module/library can now be used from Javascript or Typescript using an ES6 style import syntax

```
import { func1, func2 } from 'mymodule'
```

If this is Typescript, the typings of the 2 functions will automatically be imported too.

Comment: Somehow, this still doesn't work.. I've added a second edit with the "flow" and error message.

Comment: The approach looks OK however, it looks like it should be `import { QueryFilter } from "Module2";` in `user.ts`